# Rcpp: Floating point exception by using double type

Tags: c++, r, double, rcpp

I tried to write a simple function in cpp which I can use in rcpp, like:

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
inline static double calc(double a, double b, double c){ 
    return a - b + c;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void other_function() {
    double res = calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00);        // no error

    NumericVector resV;
    resV[0] = calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00);   // Floating point exception

    Rcout << res;                       // Floating point exception
}
```

But every time if I try to access the result of the function calc() I got an    **Floating point exception**.

If I only source the R File and call the funcion res() from the console everything seems to be fine:

```
source("myscript.R")
calc(1.00,0.00,3.00)
>> 4.00
```

What I already tried:

- convert double to NumericVector res and only working with res[0] > **not working**
- try float > **not working**
- do the calculation direct in the other_function > **same error**

**UPDATE:**

Everytime I try to call ***other_function()*** in an other function I get the following message:

```
Floating point exception
```

For example:

```
void another_function() {
    other_function();       // produce Floating point exception
}
```

If I call the other_function() directly in R everything is fine!

Also this code (thanks to snake_style) didn´t work for me:

```
NumericVector resV = NumericVector::create(progressionC(1.00, 0.00, 3.00));
```

---

## Solved

**I solved the problem** by simple reinstall the Rcpp package. I don´t know why I got this error... anyway, now it works.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. What OS & compiler do you use? What's the exact error message? But since the data isn't assigned, I would suggest telling the compiler how large a vector you need, e.g. `NumericVector resV(1);`.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @RalfStubner -- the C++ code compiles fine for me with no warnings or errors, and calling `other_function()` from R results in no errors. Without more information, it's very unlikely anyone will be able to help you, and your question may end up closed as not reproducible (or some similar reason). Helpful information to add to your post include: (1) Your OS; (2) your compiler; (3) the exact text of the error message; (4) What do you mean by "If I only source the R File"? Does "the R file" include a call to `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` to compile your code?

Comment: Same here, that works.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I use the rcpp package (last version) and R version 3.5.1.

Comment: I updated the original request to explain my problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
NumericVector resV = NumericVector::create(calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but I want to store my failed attempts at reproducing this issue. I am using R 3.5.1 on Debian stable with gcc 6.3. I used the following code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
inline static double calc(double a, double b, double c){ 
  return a - b + c;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void other_function() {
  double res = calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00);        // no error

  NumericVector resV;
  resV[0] = calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00);   // Floating point exception

  NumericVector resV1(1);
  resV1[0] = calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00);   // Floating point exception

  NumericVector resV2 = NumericVector::create(calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00));
  Rcout << res << "/" << resV << "/" << resV1 << "/" << resV2;                       // Floating point exception
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void another_function() {
  other_function();       // produce Floating point exception
}

/*** R
calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00)
other_function()
another_function()
*/
```

Calling `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` compiles this code and produces the following output:

```
> calc(1.00, 0.00, 3.00)
[1] 4

> other_function()
4//4/4
> another_function()
4//4/4
```

- There are no runtime errors.
- In your original code the result from `calc` is not assigned (`resV` outputs nothing).
- Assignment works if either the size of the vector is specified or if `calc` is used with the static `create` method as suggested by @snake_style.